# How to handle failover/H.A. in MassTransit for the masstransit database?

Tags: postgresql, masstransit

I can find some information on handling Failover in massTransit when it comes to the underlying Queue (RabbitMQ most prominently), but MassTransit also relies on a database for storing Jobs, JobConfigs and Job history. (We want to use masstransit for out-of-process tasks).

There is little to no information on how to set this up for handling outages. We use PostgreSQL, which doesn't support a multi-master setup.

I'd like to know if there is a recommended way of setting this up in a way that makes MassTransit resilient to outages, for example in a situation where there are 3 separate geolocations.

Especially for Postgres, there would be one R/W server, and possibly multiple RO replicas. This would mean that MassTransit would only be able to use that one server to write to. If it goes down, the whole service would presumably go down. It might also be that the RO replicas can still function and that masstransit will simply refuse new jobs if it can't write to the database.

I can imagine having three completely separate database servers, meaning that the jobs and job configs are per server (or location), and that only the (rabbitMQ) queue is shared (and has HA configured). Will that work, or would this "confuse" masstransit, because the workers might rely on having the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job service sagas must be stored in a single database per broker.

As for making PGSQL resilient, that's a separate concern and I have no comment.